# Regex matching, but not inside latex environment

Tags: regex, latex, notepad++, environment

I want to replace quotation marks in a latex document. It's written in German, which means that all quotation marks should be of the form "´text"' but some editors of the document have used these: "text", ´´text''.
The complication here is, that the document contains highlighted code using the lstlisting enviroment. In there the quotation marks should not be replaced.

I have a regex, that matches text inside the unwanted quotes, even if there are multiple words:

```
((``((\w+\s*)+)'')|("((\w+\s*)+)"))
```

I also have a regex, that matches a string ("asdf" in this case), only if it is not inside the lstlisting environment:

```
"asdf"(?=((?!\\end\{lstlisting\}).)*\\begin\{lstlisting\}?)
```

They work fine on their own, but when I combine them like this:

```
((``((\w+\s*)+)'')|("((\w+\s*)+)"))(?=((?!\\end\{lstlisting\}).)*\\begin\{lstlisting\}?)
```

some of the quoted strings, that should be matched are not and additionally the whole document is matched.

PS: I am currently using notepad++ for matching, because it allows . to match \n

[EDIT]: It works fine, as long as I limit the first part to single words:

```
((``((\w)+)'')|("((\w)+)"))(?=((?!\\end\{lstlisting\}).)*\\begin\{lstlisting\}?)
```

Comment: *They work fine on their own, but when I combine them* - then do not combine, run them on their own.

Comment: I need to combine them, because I want to match strings, found by the first regex, but only in the cases, constrained by the second.

Comment: You say `((\`\`((\w)+)'')|("((\w)+)"))(?=((?!\\end\{lstlisting\}).)*\\begin\{lstlisting\}?)` works fine with single words. But `\w+` matches a single word. Try `(\`\`.*?''|".*?")(?=(?:(?!\\end\{lstlisting\}).)*\\begin\{lstlisting\}?)`

Comment: I know that \w+ only matches single words, that's why I use (\w+\s*)+ to match multiple words.
Your suggestion has one disadvantage:
In a case like this: "text" more text "text2" only text and text2 should be matched, but " more text " also is.

Comment: This `(\w+\s*)+` might cause issues, you'd better use `[\w\s]+`. However, I feel no one can help you enough until you provide some sample input you have trouble with.

Comment: actually, your last suggestion solved my problem!

Thank you very much!

If you write it down as an answer to the question, I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match words with whitespaces, you can use

```
(``[\w\s]+''|"[\w\s]+")(?=(?:(?!\\end\{lstlisting\}).)*\\begin\{lstlisting\}?)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY3uV4/1)

If you have spaces only between ``` `` ``` and `''`,  or between `"`s, you will need to unroll the `[\w\s]+` part as `\w+(?:\s+\w+)*`.